# What sort of math deals with thermodynamics inside of semiconductors?

Tags: thermodynamics, semiconductor-physics

That is to say, how would one consider the thermodynamics of a complex chip like a modern CPU?

I hear that designing the thermal efficiency of such systems is very difficult. I'm not sure why, though, and I am interested.

- On the one hand, I bet the heat is somehow a function of the total power in the system.
- On the other hand, as individual bits are flipped, I imagine the heat migrates around the dai.

Obviously, this is a deep topic, but if there is a dedicated field of study that relates to this sort of problem, it would be very good to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: This question might get better answers at [engineering.stackexchange.com](http://engineering.stackexchange.com) (although that site might still be in private beta).

Comment: I'm more concerned in the math than than the engineering, but if I don't get a good answer here, I'll migrate it for sure.

Comment: The math is fairly straightforward: numerically solve a partial differential equation. The details (engineering) are more complex, like knowing what is important to model and how to solve the equations efficiently.

Comment: It's useful to realize that a CPU die is really, really flat. For practical purposes, it's 2D. There's not a lot _inside_ the semiconductor, really.

Answer (score 2):

These problems are typically solved by a approximate numerical solutions to the partial differential equations for [heat transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer), including conduction, convection, and radiation, using [finite elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) or related techniques.

You don't normally worry about the thermal effect of individual bits being flipped, though if you were designing a package for a semiconductor device you might consider the different amounts of power consumed by major subcircuits within the IC such as CPU, FPU, memory, etc. If you are designing at the board or system level, you typically simply consider the whole chip as a source of heat in your system.

Comment: So given this knowledge, what is the major challange/impediment to good heat management in ICs? Is it a materials/engineering issue at this point? I hear lots about leakage being very hard to predict.

Comment: The major challenge is that we can make ICs that consume a great deal of power in a small volume, and we don't wish to spend much money removing the heat from them.

Comment: Leakage is one of the reasons that chips produce more heat than we'd like them to, and it has become more important as device geometries have shrunk. But it's not really solvable as a thermodynamics problem, it's more of a device design and device processing problem.